# Build search filter on form to find records

Tags: database, ms-access, search, filter, vba

I have a form TimeCardSplit that is a split form. I would like to be able to search its record source, EmployeeWorkLog for records based on specific fields to populate the form for corrections.

I have two comboboxes, a textbox and a listbox I would like to use to filter my results.They are cboSearchEmployee, cboSearchJob, tboSearchDate and lstSearch. I would like to have the lstSearch show all the records in EmployeeWorkLog and be able to filter it down by using cboSearchEmployee, cboSearchJob and tboSearchDate. Once the records have been filtered down enough I like to then be able to double click on them in lstSearch and bring them up in the form TimeCardSplit.

I appreciate any advice that can be given.

Thanks for looking.

I have done more searching and have decided to move to a subform rather than using a splitform. I discovered I can filter the subform with the following code.

```
Private Sub cboSearchJob_AfterUpdate()
 If IsNull(Me.cboSearchJob) Then
    Me.cldTimeCard.Form.Filter = ""
    Me.cldTimeCard.Form.FilterOn = False
Else
    Me.cldTimeCard.Form.Filter = "[JobID]=" & Me.cboSearchJob
    Me.cldTimeCard.Form.FilterOn = True
End If
 Exit Sub
  End Sub
```

Now I'm trying to find a function to double click on a row once filtered to bring it into the form. Currently I'm using...

```
Private Sub cboJob_DblClick(Cancel As Integer)
    DoCmd.OpenForm "Try", , , "[JobID] = " & Me!JobID
End Sub
```

This is of course only in the one combobox in my subform. although this works it will only bring the first instance of my filtering results into the form, not the specific row I double click on.

So here is my new question. Is there a better place to put this code or similar code to populate the form with the row I'm double clicking on?

Thanks again for looking.

Comment: What have you written? What issues are you having? I don't believe StackOverflow is here to provide a full solution when there isn't an issue at hand.

Comment: Please do some research first. You already have the right keywords as tags or in your headline, where you can find Posts in StackOverflow. If you have a specific problem you can ask for example by showing code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I have found and it works great. I was given the solution by June7 [here](http://www.accessforums.net/forms/filter-subform-multiple-combo-boxes-date-ranges-55456.html). I'm very grateful for the help.

```
enter Private Sub cmdFilter_Click()
Dim strWhere As String
Dim lngLen As Long
Const conJetDate = "\#mm\/dd\/yy\#"   

 If Not IsNull(Me.cboSearchJob) Then
    strWhere = strWhere & "([JobID] = " & Me.cboSearchJob & ") AND "
End If

If Not IsNull(Me.cboSearchEmployee) Then
    strWhere = strWhere & "([EmployeeID] = " & Me.cboSearchEmployee & ") AND "
End If

If Not IsNull(Me.cboSearchService) Then
    strWhere = strWhere & "([ServiceID] = " & Me.cboSearchService & ") AND "
End If

If Not IsNull(Me.tboStartDate) Then
    strWhere = strWhere & "([DateWorked] >= " & Format(Me.tboStartDate, conJetDate) & ") AND "
End If
If Not IsNull(Me.tboEndDate) Then   
    strWhere = strWhere & "([DateWorked] < " & Format(Me.tboEndDate + 1, conJetDate) & ") AND "
End If
lngLen = Len(strWhere) - 5
If lngLen <= 0 Then     
    MsgBox "No criteria", vbInformation, "Nothing to do."
Else                    
    strWhere = Left$(strWhere, lngLen)  

    Me.cldTimeCard.Form.Filter = strWhere
    Me.cldTimeCard.Form.FilterOn = True
End If
```

End Subcode here

Thanks Everyone for taking a look and giving me a hand to get this accomplished. Now onto the next...